# Minimizing chunks in a matrix

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have the following matrix:

[image: Original matrix]

The matrix can be broken down into chunks such that each chunk must, for all rows, have the same number of columns where the value is marked true for that row.

For example, the following chunk is valid:

[image: Valid chunk example 1]

This means that rows do not have to be contiguous.

Columns do not have to be contiguous either, as the following is a valid chunk:

[image: Valid chunk example 2]

However, the following is invalid:

[image: Invalid chunk example]

That said, what is an algorithm that can be used to select chunks such that the minimal number of chunks will be used when finding all the chunks?

Given the example, above, the proper solution is (items with the same color represent a valid chunk):

[image: Solution to chunking problem 1]

In the above example, three is the minimal number of chunks that this can be broken down into.

Note that the following is also a valid solution:

[image: Solution to chunking problem 2]

There's not a preference to the solutions, really, just to get the least number of chunks.

I thought of counting using adjacent cells, but that doesn't account for the fact that the column values don't have to be contiguous.

I believe the key lies in finding the chunks with the largest area given the constraints, removing those items, and then repeating.

Taking that approach, the solution is:

[image: Solution to chunking problem 3]

But how to traverse the matrix and find the largest area is eluding me.

Also note, that if you want to reshuffle the rows and/or columns during the operations, that's a valid operation (in order to find the largest area), but I'd imagine you can only do it after you remove the largest areas from the matrix (after one area is found and moving onto the next).

Comment: This problem may be reformulated as "minimum biclique decomposition". This paper (pdf) proves its NP-hardness: ["Complexity of minimum biclique decomposition of bipartite graphs" by J. Amilhastre](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.52.9322&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: what are you planning to do with it?

Comment: @didierc there is a service which will be called.  Think of the coordinates as key value pairs.  It's in my interests to make the calls as large as possible.

Comment: Ok, then. I think I have a solution, but it involves computing the powerset of a powerset (with some constraints on the second one). I don't think it would be very useful in your case (I was thinking of a fixed size matrix, with integers as columns to speed up processing so that in practice the exponential complexity could be somewhat mitigated). I'll verify it to be certain that it indeed works, if so I'll post it ftr.

Comment: @didierc It could be integers as columns, the original values for the X and Y coordinates can be mapped back in the end.

Comment: It might help to note that the number of chunks is bound by the number of rows/columns as upper limit. A possible approach could be a backtracking or A* search. The next step in the search is either adding cell(s) to an existing chunk or opening a new chunk unless the upper bound is reached already.

Comment: @AxelKemper indeed, the worst solution reported by my algorithm is always the columns as chunks. Interesting approach!

Comment: @AxelKemper Which is it?  Rows or columns?  And how did you come about this?

Comment: @casperOne If you have r rows and c columns, min(r, c) is an upper bound for the number of chunks. You can always collect all 'TRUE' fields of a column into a chunk. The same is true for the rows. For enumeration algorithms it help to prune the search space if you have tight bounds.

Comment: Do I read that correctly that you are not necessarily looking for an optimal solution? That will make an enormous difference in this problem's complexity.

Comment: @PaulDraper I've rolled my question back.  Better not to change the requirements now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing [circuit minimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_minimization) on a truth table. For 4x4 truth tables, you can use a [K map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_maps). The [Quine-McCluskey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm) is a generalization that can handle larger truth tables.

Keep in mind the problem is NP-Hard, so depending on the size of your truth tables, this problem can quickly grow to a size that is intractable.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I propose is fairly straightforward, but very time consuming.

It can be decomposed in 4 major steps:

1. find all the existing patterns in the matrix,
2. find all the possible combinations of these patterns,
3. remove all the incomplete pattern sets,
4. scan the remaining list to get the set with the minimum number of elements

First of, the algorithm below works on either column or row major matrices. I chose column for the explanations, but you may swap it for rows at your convenience, as long as it remains consistent accross the whole process.

The sample code accompanying the answer is in OCaml, but doesn't use any specific feature of the language, so it should be easy to port to other ML dialects.

### Step 1:

Each column can be seen as a bit vector. Observe that a pattern (what you call chunk in your question) can be constructed by intersecting (ie. *and* ing) all the columns, or all the rows composing it, or even a combinations. So the first step is really about producing all the combinations of rows and columns (the powerset of the matrix' rows and columns if you will), intersecting them at the same time, and filter out the duplicates.

We consider the following interface for a matrix datatype:

```
 module type MATRIX = sig
    type t
    val w : int (* the width of the matrix *)
    val h : int  (* the height ........             *)
    val get : t -> int -> int -> bool  (* cell value getter *)

end
```

Now let's have a look at this step's code:

```
let clength = M.h
let rlength = M.w

(* the vector datatype used throughought the algorithm
   operator on this type are in the module V *)
type vector = V.t

(* a pattern description and comparison operators *)
module Pattern = struct
    type t = {
        w : int; (* width of thd pattern *)
        h : int; (* height of the pattern *)
        rows : vector; (* which rows of the matrix are used *)
        cols : vector; (* which columns... *)
    }
    let compare a b = Pervasives.compare a b
    let equal a b = compare a b = 0
end
(* pattern set : let us store patterns without duplicates *)
module PS = Set.Make(Pattern)

(* a simple recursive loop on @f @k times *)
let rec fold f acc k =
    if k < 0 
    then acc
    else fold f (f acc k) (pred k)

(* extract a column/row of the given matrix *)
let cr_extract mget len =
    fold (fun v j -> if mget j then V.set v j else v) (V.null len) (pred len)

let col_extract m i = cr_extract (fun j -> M.get m i j) clength
let row_extract m i = cr_extract (fun j -> M.get m j i) rlength

(* encode a single column as a pattern *)
let col_encode c i =
    { w = 1; h = count c; rows = V.set (V.null clength) i; cols = c }

let row_encode r i =
    { h = 1; w = count r; cols = V.set (V.null rlength) i; rows = r }

(* try to add a column to a pattern *)
let col_intersect p c i =
    let col = V.l_and p.cols c in
    let h = V.count col in
    if h > 0 
    then
        let row = V.set (V.copy p.rows) i in
        Some {w = V.count row; h = h; rows = row; clos = col}
    else None

let row_intersect p r i =
    let row = V.l_and p.rows r in
    let w = V.count row in
    if w > 0
    then
        let col = V.set (V.copy p.cols) i in
        Some { w = w; h = V.count col; rows = row; cols = col }
    else None

let build_patterns m =
    let bp k ps extract encode intersect =
        let build (l,k) =
            let c = extract m k in
            let u = encode c k in
            let fld p ps =
                match intersect p c k with
                      None         -> l
                    | Some npc -> PS.add npc ps
             in
             PS.fold fld (PS.add u q) q, succ k
        in
        fst (fold (fun res _ -> build res) (ps, 0) k)
    in
    let ps = bp (pred rlength) PS.empty col_extract col_encode col_intersect in
    let ps = bp (pred clength) ps row_extract row_encode row_intersect in
    PS.elements ps
```

The V module must comply with the following signature for the whole algorithm:

```
module type V = sig
    type t
    val null : int -> t  (* the null vector, ie. with all entries equal to false *)
    val copy : t -> t (* copy operator *)
    val get : t -> int -> bool (* get the nth element *)
    val set : t -> int -> t (* set the nth element to true *)
    val l_and : t -> t -> t (* intersection operator, ie. logical and *)
    val l_or : t -> t -> t (* logical or *)
    val count : t -> int (* number of elements set to true *)
    val equal : t -> t -> bool (* equality predicate *)
end
```

### Step 2:

Combining the patterns can also be seen as a powerset construction, with some restrictions: A valid pattern set may only contain patterns which don't overlap. The later can be defined as true for two patterns if both contain at least one common matrix cell.
With the pattern data structure used above, the overlap predicate is quite simple:

```
let overlap p1 p2 =
    let nullc = V.null h
    and nullr = V.null w in
    let o v1 v2 n = not (V.equal (V.l_and v1 v2) n) in
    o p1.rows p2.rows nullr && o p1.cols p2.cols nullc
```

The `cols` and `rows` of the pattern record indicate which coordinates in the matrix are included in the pattern. Thus a *logical and* on both fields will tell us if the patterns overlap.

For including a pattern in a pattern set, we must ensure that it does not overlap with any pattern of the set.

```
type pset = {
    n : int; (* number of patterns in the set *)
    pats : pattern list;
}

let overlap sp p =
    List.exists (fun x -> overlap x p) sp.pats

let scombine sp p =
    if overlap sp p
    then None
    else Some {
        n = sp.n + 1;
        pats = p::sp.pats;
    }

let build_pattern_sets l =
    let pset l p = 
        let sp = { n = 1; pats = [p] } in
        List.fold_left (fun l spx -> 
            match scombine spx p with
                None -> l
             | Some nsp -> nsp::l
        ) (sp::l) l
    in List.fold_left pset [] l
```

This step produces a lot of sets, and thus is very memory and computation intensive. It's certainly the weak point of this solution, but I don't see yet how to reduce the fold.

### Step 3:

A pattern set is incomplete if when rebuilding the matrix with it, we do not obtain the original one. So the process is rather simple.

```
let build_matrix ps w =
    let add m p =
        let rec add_col p i = function
            | []     -> []
            | c::cs -> 
                let c = 
                    if V.get p.rows i
                    then V.l_or c p.cols
                    else c
                in c::(add_col p (succ i) cs)
        in add_col p 0 m
    in
    (* null matrix as a list of null vectors *)
    let m = fold (fun l _ -> V.null clength::l) [] (pred rlength) in
    List.fold_left add m ps.pats

let drop_incomplete_sets m l =
    (* convert the matrix to a list of columns *)
    let m' = fold (fun l k -> col_extract m k ::l) [] (pred rlength) in
    let complete m sp =
        let m' = build_matrix sp in
        m = m'
    in List.filter (fun x -> complete m' x) l
```

### Step 4:

The last step is just selecting the set with the smallest number of elements:

```
let smallest_set l =
    let smallest ps1 ps2 = if ps1.n < ps2.n then ps1 else ps2 in
    match l with
        | []    -> assert false (* there should be at least 1 solution *)
        | h::t  -> List.fold_left smallest h t
```

The whole computation is then just the chaining of each steps:

```
let compute m =
   let (|>) f g = g f in
   build_patterns m |> build_pattern_sets |> drop_incomplete_sets m |> smallest_set
```

### Notes

The algorithm above constructs a powerset of a powerset, with some limited filtering. There isn't as far as I know a way to reduce the search (as mentioned in a comment, if this is a NP hard problem, there isn't any).

This algorithm checks all the possible solutions, and correctly returns an optimal one (tested with many matrices, including the one given in the problem description.

One quick remark regarding the heuristic you propose in your question:

it could be easily implemented using the first step, removing the largest pattern found, and recursing. That would yeld a solution much more rapidly than my algorithm. However, the solution found may not be optimal.

For instance, consider the following matrix:

```
.x...
.xxx
xxx.
...x.
```

The central 4 cell chunck is the largest which may be found, but the set using it would comprise 5 patterns in total.

```
.1...
.223
422.
...5.
```

Yet this solution uses only 4:

```
.1...
.122
334.
...4.
```

### Update:

Link to the [full code](http://www.pastebin.ca/2313716) I wrote for this answer.

Comment: I want to vote this up, but I've shown that there are number of ways to solve the problem and reduce it to three patterns, which your solution doesn't give.  Right now, while time is a factor, the cost of an extra "chunk" outweighs the time cost, so it's important to get the minimal number of chunks.

Comment: Yes, in my remarks, I noted that I thought not all the solutions were explored. Actually, if you submit the transposed matrix of your question to my algorithm, you will get the correct answer. It seems that I must be overlooking something to discard valid possibilities along the way. I'll look into it.

Comment: fixed a small issue wrt dimensions of the matrix (which in some algorithm I implicitely assumed to be equal).

Comment: Fixed the algorithm. Now it works on the question sample input.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is strongly related to [Biclustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biclustering), for which there are many efficient algorithms (and freely available implementations). Usually you will have to specify the number `K` of clusters you expect to find; if you don't have a good idea what `K` should be, you can proceed by binary search on `K`.

In case the biclusters don't overlap, you are done, otherwise you need to do some geometry to cut them into "blocks".

Comment: I'm not sure how that could help. Here a cell value can only be true or false. Don't you need more information to discover clusters?

Comment: @didierc What do you mean by more information? Biclustering rearranges rows and columns so as to produce "blocks" of equal values; it does not really matter if the matrix only contains two distinct values.

Comment: My bad, I did not understand the description of the algorithm.

Comment: You made me realise that if you use the column or row reordering technique, you may need to do that operation several times on either dimension, in order to "unscramble" the chunks. Besides, you will have to find all the possible sequences of unscramblings, because as I demonstrated in my answer, the greedy algorithm is not optimal.